# Difficulty in defining the Relation type as an instance of the Category class

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I'm trying to define Relation a b as a Category instance. It seems to me that the composer operator is well defined and respects the associative law. When it comes to the id, I can't find a correct definition. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Data.Map as M
import Data.Set as S
import Control.Category as Cat

newtype Relation a b = R (Map a (Set b)) deriving (Show, Eq)

-- instance Cat.Category Relation where
    -- id = 
    -- (.) = (°)

-- GHC.Base.id r1
-- > R (fromList [(10,fromList "abef"),(30,fromList "GRTXa")])

r1 = R $ M.fromList [(10,S.fromList "abfe"),(30,S.fromList "aXGRT")]
r2 = R $ M.fromList [('a',S.fromList [Just "Apple",Just "Ask"]),('b',S.fromList [Just "book",Just "brother"]),('T',S.fromList [Just "Table"]),('?',S.fromList [Just "Apple",Just "brother"])]

-- ex. r1 ° r2 = R (fromList [(10,fromList [Just "Apple",Just "Ask",Just "book",Just "brother"]),(30,fromList [Just "Apple",Just "Ask",Just "Table"])])


(°) :: (Ord a, Ord k, Ord b) => Relation a k -> Relation k b -> Relation a b   
R mp1 ° R mp2
  | M.null mp1 || M.null mp2 = R M.empty 
  | otherwise = R $ M.foldrWithKey (\k s acc -> M.insert k (S.foldr (\x acc2 -> case M.lookup x mp2 of
                                                                                  Nothing -> acc2
                                                                                  Just s2 -> S.union s2 acc2
                                                                    ) S.empty s) acc
                                   ) M.empty mp1
```

Comment: I'd needs to be `{ (a,a) | a in A }`. Since your model of relation is a finite map, you can only do this if A is finite.

Comment: Unrelated question: why import `GHC.Base`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia In other definitions of Category instances I've seen define id like this. Furthermore, it obviously works by itself; that is GHC.Base.id R mp == R mp, which, in my opinion shows that the identity relationship exists on R.

Comment: @luqui So you think that I should define R as a simple Set (a,b)? So how should 'id' be defined in this case? (The composition of relation as Set of pairs seems easy to me.)

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani No the `Set (a,b)` is still required to be finite.  I would actually go for something like `a -> Set b` ("locally finite"), or maybe even `a -> b -> Bool`

Comment: @luqio Maybe like a characteristic function over a relation that compose with another one if the first one give true and the second argument is in second function's domain?

Comment: I don't understand the explanation about GHC.Base. As far as I can tell it's an internal library which is not meant to be used. It definitely has nothing to do with user-defined `Category` instances.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia It was only a tentative solution. Now, after your explanations, it seems little sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Relation` cannot be an instance of `Category`:

1. as luqui points out in the comments, `Relation` only represents finite relations (when viewed as sets of pairs), but the identity relation on an infinite set is infinite;
2. composition is not defined on all types, only on instances of `Ord`.

Here's one way to address those issues and make `Relation` an instance of `Category`:

1. add a trivial element to represent the identity relation (this is the same idea behind making a monoid out of a semigroup with `Option`);
2. make the other "nontrivial" relations carry the `Ord` instances.

This can be done using GADTs.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Relation a b where
  Id :: Relation a a
  R :: (Ord a, Ord b) => Map a (Set b) -> Relation a b

instance Category Relation where
  id = Id
  Id . r = r
  r . Id = r
  R r1 . R r2 = ...
```